# ID associated with max date in group

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

there are a ton of other related questions but I couldn't quite apply them to my situation. I am using sequelize so I'm trying to do this with as few hits to the DB as possible.

My (simplified) table is basically:

```
id      dateAcquired   staffId  skillId
44      2017-04-27     25       2
341     2018-02-01     28       2
4787    2018-04-04     25       2
8852    2020-01-31     28       2
```

I am looking for just the id of the most recent dateAcquired per staffId. (note that the most recent one might be a lower id, otherwise I would have had a solution)

```
4787
8852
```

Just in SQL using this query I get the correct date but not the correct id:

```
SELECT id, staffId, max(`dateAcquired`) 
FROM `histories` AS `history` 
WHERE `history`.`skillId` = '2' 
GROUP BY `staffId`, id
```

Results in:

```
44  2018-04-04
341 2020-01-31
```

Although I know it needs tweaking once I get the query right, my sequelize code is:

```
models.history.findAll(
      {
        attributes: [sequelize.fn("max", sequelize.col('dateAcquired')), 'id'],
        where: {skillId:id},
        group: ["id"]
      }
    ).then(maxIds => {
      let ids = maxIds.map(result =>{return result.id;});
      models.history.findAll({
        include: [
          {
            model:models.staff
          }
        ],
        where: {
          id: {
            [Op.in]: [ids]
          }
        }
      }).then(results =>
      {
        res.json(results);
      })
    })
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select h.* from histories h
where h.skillid = 2
and not exists (
  select 1 from histories  
  where skillid = h.skillid and staffid = h.staffid and dateAcquired > h.dateAcquired
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aXKKLcUUpDjR9sq8fywW6i/0).
Results:

```
| id   | dateAcquired        | staffId | skillId |
| ---- | ------------------- | ------- | ------- |
| 4787 | 2018-04-04 00:00:00 | 25      | 2       |
| 8852 | 2020-01-31 00:00:00 | 28      | 2       |
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t
   LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON t2.staffId = t.staffId AND t2.dateAcquired > t.dateAcquired
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
  AND t.skillId = 2;
```

**Explanation**

What happens is that each row from `t` joins onto any rows where the `staffId` matches and `dateAcquired` is greater. The only rows that don't join are the ones with the highest values in `dateAcquired`. We then filter out everything that *does* join in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: thanks but that orders by all results, not within the grouping of staffId's

Comment: @enfrost ah, I see. My mistake, I misunderstood the problem. I'm editing my answer now.

Comment: This is never more efficient than using a subquery, which is a shame because in some circles its popularly known as a 'strawberry' query - which is a fantastic name for a query.

Comment: @Strawberry I've removed that claim as I realise I can't provide solid evidence for it. A weird feeling, learning that something you've believed for a long time isn't necessarily true.

Comment: This method was popular because once upon a time, we didn't have the option of subqueries. It's simple to construct a data set of a million or so indexed rows and then compare performance between this and both correlated and uncorrelated subquery equivalents. If your query wins, I'll buy you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
Create table #test 
(id int,
dateAcquired date,
staffid int,
skillid int
)

Insert into #test values (44 , '2017-04-27'  ,   25   ,    2)
Insert into #test values (341 ,    '2018-02-01'   ,  28    ,   2)
Insert into #test values (4787  ,  '2018-04-04'   ,  25    ,   2)
Insert into #test values (8852 ,   '2020-01-31'   ,  28    ,   2)

select id,dateacquired
from
(
select id,dateacquired,
--ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by dateacquired order by dateacquired )
ROW_NUMBER()over( order by dateacquired desc )rn

from #test 
)a where rn<=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Several possible query patterns to return the specified result

Using an inline view (derived table) to get the latest (maximum) date_acquired for each staffid, and then a join to the base table to get the row(s) that have that latest date_acquired.

```
SELECT MAX(h.`id`) AS `id`
     , h.`staffId`
     , h.`dateacquired`
  FROM
  JOIN ( SELECT l.`staffid`
               , MAX(l.`dateacquired`) AS `max_dateacquired`
            FROM `histories` l
           WHERE l.`skillId` = '2'
           GROUP BY l.`staffid`
       ) m
  JOIN `histories` h
    ON h.`dateacquired` = m.`max_dateacquired`
    ON h.`staffid`      = m.`staffid`
   AND h.`skillId`      = '2'
 GROUP
    BY h.`staffid`
     , h.`dateacquired`
```

MySQL 8.0 introduced Window Functions, which gives us another way to get the specified result:

```
WITH w AS
( SELECT h.id
       , h.staffid
       , h.dateacquired
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY h.staffid ORDER BY h.dateacquired DESC, h.id DESC) AS _rn
    FROM `histories` h
   WHERE h.skillid = '2' 
)
SELECT w.id
     , w.staffid
     , w.dateacquired
  FROM w
 WHERE _rn = 1 
 ORDER
    BY w.staffid
```

We could also use an anti-join pattern, to retrieve rows where there isn't a later dateacquired... assuming `id` is unique in `histories` (or at least the `(staffid,dateacquired,id)` tuple is unique)

```
SELECT h.id
     , h.staffid
     , h.dateacquired
  FROM `histories` h
    -- anti-join
  LEFT
  JOIN `histories` l
    ON l.skillid  = '2'
   AND l.staffid  = h.staffid
   AND l.dateacquired >= h.dateacquired
   AND ( l.datecquired > h.dateacquired OR l.id > h.id )
 WHERE l.staffid IS NULL
   AND h.skillid = '2'
 ORDER
    BY h.staffid
```

We could accomplish the same thing, re-writing the anti-join as a NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT h.id
     , h.staffid
     , h.dateacquired
  FROM `histories` h
 WHERE h.skillid = '2'
   AND NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM `histories` l
          WHERE l.skillid  = '2'
            AND l.staffid  = h.staffid
             AND l.dateacquired >= h.dateacquired
             AND ( l.datecquired > h.dateacquired OR l.id > h.id )
       )
```

(Note that some of these queries could be simplified a tiny bit if we have a guarantee that `(staffid,skillid,dateacquired)` tuple is unique. All of the queries above do not assume such a guarantee.)